# Web scraping with Google Script, asynchronous website?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, urlfetch, ncbi

I want to **scrape** this specific information "NM_000014.5" from the RefSeq transcripts table (to be more specific I'd like to have the RefSeq Select one) of this website https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=%22A2M%22+human

I want to scrape this information using Google script in order to add it to a Google sheet table. I have already been able to **scrape** other info but this specific information is too hard to get for me. I tried to use UrlFetchApp.fetch and parsing with XmlService but it seems that this info is linked to another website...or something like that...is there a "simple" way to get that?

Comment: You might have better luck with the ncbi api

Comment: Yes I use the ncbi api for several other informations but I'm not able to find this specific info with the ncbi api...any idea ?

Comment: You might wanna ask that as a new question with [tag:ncbi] tag

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the IMPORT functions that come with Google Sheets -- specifically, either ImportXML or ImportHTML. These are great options that I have used in the past for simple site scrapes.

Here is a great article covering basic web scraping in Google Sheets with ImportXML: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheet-web-scraper/

Just right-click Inspect the site for the correct HTML tags. Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I maybe should have explain that I'm planning to use the  code for hundreds and hundreds of genes so if I use (and I did) this solution, it will reload thousands of link each time I open the sheet. I used to code a "setFormula("=IMPORTXML....)" and then copy and paste it in the cell with Google Script but this solution is not ideal...I want something more reliable